# SQLite - select rows by existance of date in given intervals

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database with two tables that looks like this:

```
Table: Position
| pk | name | ...
------------------
| 1  | pos1 | ...
| 2  | pos2 | ...


Table: Status
| pk_position | datetime | ...
----------------------
| 1           | 20170201 | ...
| 1           | 20170204 | ...
| 1           | 20170205 | ...
| 1           | 20170207 | ...
| 2           | 20170204 | ...
| 2           | 20170201 | ...
| 2           | 20170208 | ...
```

Where datetime is "YYYYMMDD" (i.e. `%Y%m%d`) and pk_position is a ForeginKey of the table Position.

I need the following: given two intervals of time `int1 = [day1:day2]` and `int2 = [day3:day4]`, I want a unique selection of `pk_position` for which there exists at least 1 row with `datetime` contained in *each* interval.

Examples (using example tables):

- `int1 = ["20170201" : "20170202"]` and `int2 = ["20170202" : "20170203"]` => (null)
- `int1 = ["20170204" : "20170205"]` and `int2 = ["20170205" : "20170206"]` => 1
- `int1 = ["20170203" : "20170204"]` and `int2 = ["20170204" : "20170205"]` => 1, 2

I tried to use the `EXISTS` but I can't find any smart way to achieve this.

Thanks!

*OBS*: I tried to keep the question as broad as possible. In reality in all my use cases the intervals will have the form [day1 : day2], [day2 : day3] (i.e. they share a common boundary), just like all examples. If doing this for a common boundary is easier, I'll be happy with a solution to this simpler problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you there (I don't have a way to test SQLite, so it wouldn't surprise me if there wasn't a missing comma, or the semicolons are wrong, or something like that, but this is the logic in SQL, adapted to SQLite as best I can without final testing):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE 
    _time_intervals
    (
    int1 TEXT, 
    int2 TEXT, 
    int1Start TEXT, 
    int1End TEXT, 
    int2Start TEXT, 
    int2End TEXT
    );

INSERT INTO 
    _time_intervals(int1, int2) 
    VALUES ( '["20170201" : "20170202"]', '["20170202" : "20170203"]' );

UPDATE _time_intervals
    SET int1Start = SUBSTR(int1, 3, 8),
    SET int1End = SUBSTR(int1, 16, 8),
    SET int2Start = SUBSTR(int2, 3, 8),
    SET int2End = SUBSTR(int2, 16, 8)

SELECT
    pk_position
FROM
(
SELECT
    s.pk_position,
    1 AS int1_counter,
    0 AS int2_counter
FROM
    Status AS s
WHERE
    s.datetime BETWEEN (SELECT int1Start FROM _time_intervals) AND  (SELECT int1End FROM _time_intervals)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    s.pk_position,
    0 AS int1_counter,
    1 AS int2_counter
FROM
    Status AS s
WHERE
    s.datetime BETWEEN  (SELECT int2Start FROM _time_intervals) AND  (SELECT int2End FROM _time_intervals)
) AS sq
GROUP BY 
    pk_position
HAVING
    SUM(int1_counter) > 0
AND
    SUM(int2_counter) > 0;

DROP TABLE _time_intervals;
```

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://sqliteonline.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/, or just [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the command-line shell.

Comment: I use sqlfiddle a lot, but the SQLite version doesn't work from the PC I was at.